# GA: Unique visitors of two websites

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have two websites (different domains) and I want to know how many unique users are visiting both sites. The best result would be:

number of unique visitors

- on website A
- on website B
- on website A and B

The websites have their own GA tracking ID. Do I have to implement the cross domain tracking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes cross domain tracking is made for exactly the same purpose.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en